# How to find out the path that will be used in `cd -`?

Tags: bash, cd

I know that it is possible to use `cd -` to switch between 2 paths:

```
user@server:~$ cd a
user@server:~/a$ cd ~/b
user@server:~/b$ cd -
/home/user/a
user@server:~/a$ cd -
/home/user/b
user@server:~/b$
```

I want to use this feature to do something with the previous path. Maybe there is some variable that points to the previous path so I can do thins like:

```
user@server:~/a$ cd ~/b
user@server:~/a$ ls -d $PREVIOUS_PATH
/home/user/a
user@server:~/a$ cp file $PREVIOUS_PATH # will copy file to /home/user/a
user@server:~/b$ cd -
```

Comment: fyi, this is also what `~-` will expand to.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Old working directory is stored in `OLDPWD` environment variable. This variable is updated every time we change directory. This also means that it is not set when we launch terminal.

```
user@server:~/a$ cd ~/b
user@server:~/a$ ls -d "$OLDPWD"
/home/user/a
user@server:~/a$ cp file "$OLDPWD" # will copy file to /home/user/a, ""
user@server:~/b$ cd -
```

Comment: *grumble* re: lack of quotes (`cp file $OLDPWD` will behave badly if that directory had spaces in its name; `cp file "$OLDPWD"` would be safer).

Comment: Thank you @CharlesDuffy, updated accordingly to have `" "`

Comment: @dlmeetei You've forgotten `ls -d "$OLDPWD"`.

Comment: @GKFX, My bad. Thanks